# handshake_failure when connect using mule 3.6 https connector

Tags: mule, tls1.2

I'm trying to connect third party secured url using mule https connector end point. here is the mule https connector

```
    <https:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="false" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" sendTcpNoDelay="true" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS"> 
    <service-overrides sessionHandler="org.mule.session.NullSessionHandler"/>
    <https:tls-key-store path="key.jks" keyPassword="pwd" storePassword="pwd"></https:tls-key-store>  
</https:connector>
```

here is the out bound end point

```
          <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="https://url" responseTimeout="180000" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" user="user" password="pwd" contentType="application/soap+xml" doc:name="HTTP"> 
        <set-property propertyName="prop1" value="11"></set-property>  
        <set-property propertyName="prop2" value="22"></set-property>  
    </https:outbound-endpoint>
```

When I trying to connect it gave me the hand shake failure error

```
Exception stack is:
```

1. Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException)
  sun.security.ssl.Alerts:192 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLHandshakeException.html)

in third party connection there are using 256 ciphersuite and TLS versions 1.0 1.1 1.2. How do I set up these configuations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by replacing the Unlimited Strength JCE jars (local_policy.jar, US_export_policy.jar) in jre security libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that configure the Tomcat servers with an HTTP (non-SSL) connector on a port 
Open a terminal window and navigate to the Tcat Server installation/bin directory. Type tcatserver6w and examine the contents under Java tab. Make sure both JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME are pointing to the right path. for more idea please refer the below link
https://docs.mulesoft.com/tcat-server/v/7.1.0/common-problems-and-solutions#ssl-tls-handshake-exception

Comment: thank you sipra for your answer. actually  i'm not using tomcat server. i'm only using the mule server. I able to solve this problem by replacing the Unlimited Strength JCE jars (local_policy.jar, US_export_policy.jar) in jre security libs folder